# In Visual studio 2015 toolbox there is no 'busy bar' tool how to add this in the toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to add new toolbox items into existing toolbox of visual-studio 2015. I can find no 'busy bar' tool item. Do please suggest a possible way to get this in visual-studio 2015.

Comment: Do you mean a progressbar?

Comment: What is a "busy bar"?

Comment: Busy bar is an advanced win forms progress control.